# Undefined Reference To, VSCODE, Cant Link static library to header files

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-code, linker-errors, undefined-reference, vscode-tasks

I have a problem and I can't fix it no matter what I do. My university is using Stanford CS106B c++ Library for a course and only IDE that seems to work on windows is Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express.

I would like to write assignments in Visual Studio Code but I can't link header files with complied static library.

My VSCode Extensions: C/C++, C++ Intellisense, Code Runner.
My Compiler: GCC(6.3.0) MinGW64

Details: This is how the assignment folder looks like. In the StanfordCPPLib folder, there are header files and compiled .lib file. in the numeric Conversions folder is .CPP file that I have to fill in.

```
├───1 - Numeric Conversions
│   ├───Numeric Conversions
│   └───StanfordCPPLib
│       └───private
|
└───.vscode
```

VSCode can see those header files (when I press CTRL and hover over them it shows contents), but cant Link them to .lib file, thus I get error `Undefined reference to...`.

I do not know how to set up tasks.JSON file which seems to be the problem(this was pointed out to me on multiple forums).

Comment: use a build tool like `Make`, `CMake`, `MSBuild`

Comment: @rioV8 Can you be more specific? As I said I don't know how the linking process works yet. I tried to add CMake but I just got confused. If it's not too bothersome please give more details :D

Comment: find some books/sites about building C/C++ programs with `Make` `GNU Make`, `autoconf`, `configure`,..... Yes creating a build file looks complicates at first and CMake is no different

Comment: To be more specific - try working through this: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html from section 1.6 onwards, it really spells it out compilation and linking for you and then section 2. shows you how to construct your makefile. Then getting this to work with vscode, well, IIRC it works out of the box - or you add a really simple launcher that calls `make` ... If you get stuck post a question with your specific problem : )